# SQL Server TLS 1.2 support confirm

Tags: sql-server, tls1.2

For our production DB, we are on the following SQL version,

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)   Sep 21 2011 22:45:45   
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

From Microsoft KB:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

This SQL Server version is lower than the first build that supports TLS 1.2,

[image]

I don't think it supports TLS 1.2.

Can anyone confirm this?

I'm comparing the version numbers 10.0.5500.0 vs 10.50.6542.0 (minimum build that supports TLS 1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 v10.0.5500.0 is SQL Server 2008 with Service Pack 3 (SP3) applied. SQL Server with a version number **10.50.xxx.xxx** would be SQL Server **2008 R2** - and yes, that's a different version (not just a service pack) of SQL Server.

If you look further down in that document you linked, there's also a line for SQL Server 2008:

```
SQL Server 2008 SP4     10.0.6547.0
```

So you would need to apply SP4 to your SQL Server 2008 instance (and possibly also that update that is linked in your document) in order for it to support TLS 1.2

Comment: thanks for the reply. My SQL server version is definitely not R2 correct?

Comment: @tinker: you appear to have SQL Server **2008** (without the R2 features)